# How many copies of MS Word are required?

Tags: microsoft-word, iis

I have an ASP.NET application that is using MS Word to do som processing of a document. So basically a request comes into IIS into an MVC applicaiton and the application takes a Word DOCX file and applies some changes to the DOCX file and produces a new one. All this processing is done under the context of the IIS user. So is a single user licence sufficient for Word? Or as this is done via a web application that can have multiple concurrent users of Word at any instant in time, does this require more licences?

Comment: 0 copies, use the [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) to edit the DOCX instead. Word is not designed to be used with automation when run by a non "interactive desktop" user (windows services)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing as you suggest means you are *multiplexing* Word's functionality to multiple users. In which case you could possibly need a licence for EACH USER that uses it.

There are also many security and functionality problems you can run into doing server-side Office automation; for that reason Microsoft doesn't support it being used in that way, regardless of licencing.

> Microsoft does not recommend or support server-side Automation of Office.

Do as Scott suggests in his comment and move away from Word Automation (yuck ;) ) and instead modify the DOCX file(s) directly using the [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425):

> The Open XML SDK 2.5 simplifies the task of manipulating Open XML packages and the underlying Open XML schema elements within a package. The Open XML Application Programming Interface (API) encapsulates many common tasks that developers perform on Open XML packages, so you can perform complex operations with just a few lines of code.

Plus it's a lot easier if you use a library like [PowerTools for Open XML](https://powertools.codeplex.com/).

> PowerTools for Open XML contains source code and guidance for accomplishing various common tasks using the Open XML SDK

Doing that will make it so you don't need Word on the server at all.

Additional information is available straight from the source, Microsoft: [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: @Techie007 This is not my implementation. I am reviewing some code with regard to this. I am trying to find a definitive answer as to how many licences are needed as the current developers maintain only a single copy is required. That does not seem right to me so I am looking for clarification.

Comment: @TheEdge, SuperUser is for technical questions not licensing or legal questions.  You should probably contact Microsoft with your question about licensing their product.  They will be able to provide you with the best answer, although Techie's answer states that your scenario is not supported, so they may not be able to help you either.

Comment: @heavyd makes a good point. You can chat online with a Microsoft licensing specialist; they're pretty helpful.

Comment: Thanks guys will do.... figured there might be a sysadmin that had done this before so the question seemed relevant here.

Comment: @TheEdge Check this out: http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/briefs/multiplexing.aspx  It's about multiplexing SQL, TFS and Project server, but it might help you find some more directly related information. I thing briantist makes a good suggestion, just call MS.